# Why is wingsuit water landing without opening a parachute not a survivable event?

Tags: forces, collision, estimation, aerodynamics, free-fall

According to this YT [video](https://youtu.be/CnVJ8yOTEFs), just before this wingsuit flyer opened his parachute his speed was below 90 KPH. When you jump off a 100 foot cliff your impact velocity is around 87 KPH and people have jumped from even higher altitudes into water and survived without injuries. So, why is it that water landing in a wingsuit without opening the parachute is not a survivable event?

Comment: Wingsuit landings on water are dangerous, but they definitely are survivable.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o2xmAWS4akE

Comment: @DavidWhite Due to your good rep I'll assume that was not a joke? I mean, you cannot seriously think that video was real?

Comment: well, guess what: that wingsuit water landing was real

Comment: @DeanKuga, I suspect it was real.  If you land on the water at the correct angle, you will skid for some distance.  At some point, you will most likely roll on top of the water, but that roll is not fatal.  If, on the other hand, you hit the water at anything other than a very shallow angle, severe injury or death are likely.

Comment: @DavidWhite No it wasn't the guy actually admitted it was fake the very next week... https://www.nbcnews.com/id/wbna46822559